# Laravel: using count in the where clause throwing error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel project. I am trying to write an Eloquent where I need to use raw where clause for COUNT.

This is my query.

```
$eligibleReceivers = ReceiverDevice::havingRaw('COUNT(phone_number) < 10')
            ->having('phone_number', '!=', $device->phone_number)
            ->groupBy('phone_number')->get();
```

I am trying to select the records where records the same phone_number must be less than 10.

When I run the code, I am getting the following error.

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'fork.receiver_devices.id' isn't in GROUP BY at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:331)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(331): PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
#1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(662): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(338): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2149): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2137): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2609): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2138): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(545): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get(Array)
#9 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(529): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels(Array)
#10 /var/www/app/Http/Requests/RegisterDeviceRequest.php(72): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get()
#11 /var/www/app/Http/Requests/RegisterDeviceRequest.php(60): App\\Http\\Requests\\RegisterDeviceRequest->registerReceiversFor(Object(App\\Models\\ClientDevice))
#12 /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterDeviceController.php(14): App\\Http\\Requests\\RegisterDeviceRequest->persist()
#13 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\RegisterDeviceController->store(Object(App\\Http\\Requests\\RegisterDeviceRequest))
#14 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
#16 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\RegisterDeviceController), 'store')
#17 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#18 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this :-
In config\database.php in mysql array

Set 'strict' => false // to disable all.